# How to send new line whatsapp message using PHP/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=XXXXXXXXXX&text=Hello%0AHow%20R%20U?

O/P:

[image: Whats App O/P]

I want this output using PHP/JavaScript:

```
Hello
How R U?
```

I have a already try encodeURI JS, urlencode PHP, \n, br html, nltobr, \r\n, etc,...

But it did't worked.

Comment: Hi! This link of api works? Have price for use? Limit messages per day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]you have to encodeURI first:-

```
var whatsappMessage= "My First"+"\r\n\r\n"+"Message for Test";

 whatsappMessage = window.encodeURIComponent(whatsappMessage);
```

Sending encoded message as parameter like :-

```
send?text=whatsappMessage
```

Comment: can you please share the full script?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">

var whatsappMessage= "My First"+"\r\n\r\n"+"Message for Test";

whatsappMessage = window.encodeURIComponent(whatsappMessage);

document.getElementById("<?php echo $id; ?>-whatsapp-link").setAttribute("href", ("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=XXXXXXXXX&text=" + whatsappMessage));

</script>`

Comment: click on send and you will see the line break

Comment: Please check the screenshot attached in my answer.

Comment: @RakeshJakhar tried unable to send message. need help?

Answer (score 0):

1. In PHP, for whatsapp message, to have line break, no javascript required:

```
$message = 'Hello'. urlencode("\n"). 'How R U?';
```

2. Or create a variable to be used on any line:

```
$break = urlencode("\n");
```